# how to integrate magento minicart in wordpress

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I am in the process of implementing minicart in wordpress. How do we can call minicart of magento in wordpress .

Answer (score 1):

My favorite route of getting Magento related content on a WordPress page/post is to use the plugin called [Mage Enabler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mage-enabler/) by [Richard Feraro](http://mysillypointofview.richardferaro.com/2010/05/11/mage-enabler/). It’s pretty easy to setup for an experienced developer. You just give the absolute local path to the Mage.php file in the Mage Enabler settings and then copy the `‘/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php’` to the `‘/magento/app/code/local/Mage/Core/functions.php’` and adjust the translator function that both Magento and WordPress share. You can go to the Plugin page for more info.

The great thing about this plugin is you can bring into your WordPress install any session, cookies or variables that were previously exclusive to Magento. This way you can pull in the mini shipping cart that will carry over the number of items in the cart on the WordPress pages. A great feature to have!

Comment: i am hoping to have a hint that how to call , with the function of magento .

Comment: Please refer to the link:

http://mysillypointofview.richardferaro.com/2010/05/11/mage-enabler/

Comment: i already have every thing setup , but the point is when i click on + button it should be increment the quantity dynamically on cart as well .